# Using apache beam version 2.44.0 facing issue java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1.BigQueryWriteClient

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Previously I am using this apache beam version `2.28.0` but this version is now deprecated. I am trying to update new version `2.44.0` but getting issue related to class not found `com.google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1.BigQueryWriteClient`

I have tried including `bigquery-storage-api` so that class should be available but that is also not working

Comment: Please can you share your `pom.xml` file ?

Comment: Hi Mazlum, I able to resolve this issue. This issue due to library bom version mismatch, Thanks for replying

Comment: Hi @DevendraBhandari I posted your comment as a community answer, please consider accepting and upvoting it. Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research.

Answer (score 1):

@Devendra Bhandari, As you have mentioned in the comment, the issue is due to the library bom version mismatch.

Posting the answer as community wiki for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.
Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.